# ERROR 404 - The requested resource is not available.[PHP]

Tags: php, curl

I make some CURL request on REST API, which looks like this:

```
$data = array (
    "caseNumber" => "123456789" 
    );

// json encode data

$data_string = json_encode($data); 

// the token

$token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host.$path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
));       

// execute the request
$output = curl_exec($ch);   
echo $output;
```

In general it looks really OKEY from my point of view, how ever I try this ECHO just kick apache ass.

I already try to `var_dump()` and `print()` it as well, but still same result and without any better description I don't know how to debug this.
Can somebody give an advise or is here anyone who see a bug in my code?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I found out that ERROR comes out from backend not from my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$output` should be a boolean value indicating the success or failure of the request. It will not contain anything else. In order to get the result of the operation, try something like this:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if ($output === false) {
    print 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    print 'Request completed. Output: ' . $output;
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hi @borfast, this throw me: Request completed. Output: and error below :)

Comment: @Andurit, so you're saying that it goes to the second branch of the if() condition, even though the request failed?

Comment: Yea, acctualy find out error. It comes from apache of the server I make request on.
So in general my code works but webservice return me apache error :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but if it works, great. Keep in mind, though, that the way I detailed in my answer is the correct way of doing requests with cURL in PHP. In fact, PHP's docs about it have a pretty similar example: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php